# Autofill excel date after entering month of

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, formula

I am creating an excel template and want to auto populate the dates in my table.

Above their is a line where the dates included are written in EX. 10/01/14 - 10/31/14.

I want the dates in my table to be filled in when i enter those dates.

Do I need to make it two cells, one start date and one end date?

What formula do i need to use?

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell containing the pair of dates separated by a dash and run this small macro:

```
Sub DateMaker()
    Dim v As String, d1 As Date, d2 As Date, i As Long
    v = ActiveCell.Text
    ary = Split(v, "-")
    d1 = DateValue(Trim(ary(0)))
    d2 = DateValue(Trim(ary(1)))
    Set r = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)
    For i = 1 To Rows.Count
        r.Value = d1
        d1 = d1 + 1
        If d1 > d2 Then Exit Sub
        Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage *without using the Table* then Try This:

select entire entry range (blank cells where date would reside later) and insert this formula :

`=LEFT($L$3;8)+(ROW()-n)` 
here, n= row no of first entry and L3 cell contain the date range.

After pasting the above formula press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to make it array formula.

Or, you might follow the macro (code) way suggested in previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

2 cells are the easiest - you can then `CONCATENATE` them to give the display how you want, and hide the **Start** and **End** columns

In the first (start) cell, put your starting date.
For the ending date, use `=EOMONTH([@Start],0)`

For 2nd month use either `=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,1)` or `=B2+1` as the start date, and keep `=EOMONTH([@Start],0)` as the end date.  The table will then autofill with the start and end date for each month as you grow the table.